# How can I use Olacabs search functionality in my Android App?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to get distance from from user current locations to any nearest cab which are stored in `OlaCabs(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.olacabs.customer&hl=en)` database, so searched for there API and then I found this and tried it:

1. I went to http://docs.console.olacabs.com/ola and typed lat and lng for a city 
   and tried to get result. But it always returned me *"error": "Authorization field missing"* in the response. I have tried for more than one cities but always got this response.
2. One more thing that I want to ask is about the `API key`. Do I need to contact to this service provider to get that or it is something else. Please do provide an example.

Comment: I have just received word from official sources, the Api is private for now and will be released for developers in near future. You can try Fiddler proxy server to check Ola Cab's api call and then try and mimic them.

Answer (score 1):

Use this API provided by olacabs to know Ride Availability
http://developers.olacabs.com/api/1

For successful call, you need to provide X-APP-TOKEN which is the Key which identifies the partner.